# Как вытащить вложенный массив, и положить в отдельный массив?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть многомерный массив. Как вытащить из него все массивы 2-го уровня и положить в отдельный массив, допустим $cats_level2?

```
    Array(
    [8] => Array
    (
        [id] => 8
        [pid] => 0
        [name] => Кузовные запчасти
        [menu_icon] => 
        [image] => kuzov.jpg
        [keywords] => 
        [description] => 
        [childs] => Array
            (
                [28] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 28
                        [pid] => 8
                        [name] => Бампера и их части
                        [menu_icon] => 
                        [image] => 
                        [keywords] => 
                        [description] => 
                        [childs] => Array
                            (
                                [29] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 29
                                        [pid] => 28
                                        [name] => Бампер передний
                                        [menu_icon] => 
                                        [image] => 
                                        [keywords] => 
                                        [description] => 
                                    )

                                [30] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 30
                                        [pid] => 28
                                        [name] => Бампер задний
                                        [menu_icon] => 
                                        [image] => 
                                        [keywords] => 
                                        [description] => 
                                    )              
                            )
                    )

                [34] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 34
                        [pid] => 8
                        [name] => Капоты и их части
                        [menu_icon] => 
                        [image] => 
                        [keywords] => 
                        [description] => 
                        [childs] => Array
                            (
                                [35] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 35
                                        [pid] => 34
                                        [name] => Капот
                                        [menu_icon] => 
                                        [image] => 
                                        [keywords] => 
                                        [description] => 
                                    )

                                [36] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 36
                                        [pid] => 34
                                        [name] => Петли капота
                                        [menu_icon] => 
                                        [image] => 
                                        [keywords] => 
                                        [description] => 
                                    )

                            )
                    )
```

Comment: В двух словах: перебираем массив через, для текущего эл-та проверяем есть ли у него вложенные массивы, если есть - добавлять в новый их. профит

Comment: `array_merge(...array_column($data, 'childs'))` что ли ?

Answer (score 0):

Можно перебрать главный массив:

```
<?
  $array = ваш массив
  $cats_level2 = []; //массив с массивами 2 уровня
  foreach ($array  as $key => $value) {
     $cats_level2[] = $value['childs']; //перебирает массив 1 порядка и наполняет массив 2
  }
?>
```

как я понял вам надо создать массив с массивами параметра childs

Answer (score -1):

```
$fdats=array(array("id"=>"8","pid"=>"0","name"=>"кузовные запчасти","menu_icon"=>"","image"=>"kuzov.jpg","keywords"=>"","description"=>"","childs"=>array(array("id"=>"8","pid"=>"0","name"=>"Бампера и их части","menu_icon"=>"","image"=>"","keywords"=>"","description"=>"","childs"=>array(array("id"=>"8","pid"=>"0","name"=>"Бампер передний","menu_icon"=>"","image"=>"","keywords"=>"","description"=>""),array("id"=>"8","pid"=>"0","name"=>"Бампер задний","menu_icon"=>"","image"=>"","keywords"=>"","description"=>""))),array("id"=>"8","pid"=>"0","name"=>"Капот и их части","menu_icon"=>"","image"=>"","keywords"=>"","description"=>"","childs"=>array(array("id"=>"8","pid"=>"0","name"=>"капот","menu_icon"=>"","image"=>"","keywords"=>"","description"=>""),array("id"=>"8","pid"=>"0","name"=>"петли капота","menu_icon"=>"","image"=>"","keywords"=>"","description"=>""))))));
```

Тренируйся сам